# If my review question on Meta is resolved, should I alter the title to reflect that?

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users, title

I recently concluded a [question reviewing another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285385/3408500) here on Meta. Does it do any good to revise the title from something like, `"Help me review this failed edit!"` to `"Help me review this failed edit! [resolved]"`?

My reasoning is that if some future user wants to make a new question with that title (whose vagueness cannot really be helped), it would be considerate to make it available to them. Reasons not to do so might run, *"We already have brackets parceled out to limited and specific uses,"* or *"Too minor!"* (whatever *that* means) or *"It's ugly, so no."* It's also only really useful once, and could be viewed as *actively encouraging the accumulation of vague questions with indistinct titles.*

Naturally, this situation is inapplicable to SO-proper, but I can see by the heaps of `"Why were my edits rejected?"` titles here on Meta that it could be useful (or at least *thoughtful*).

I don't want to delete the thread itself because the question content is still potentially valuable to future users.

Comment: Though threads on meta are generally ephemeral, putting `[resolved]` in the question title doesn't help at all. The discussion is just as important as the resolution, this isn't a hit and run support forum.

Comment: I think accepting an answer is just doing that already.

Comment: @purplehuman Does accepting an answer permit future questions with the same title, though?

Comment: @Augusta Accepting an answer doesn't mean much on meta.

Comment: @Augusta I see what you mean. But adding the title [solved] wouldn't make people avoid asking the same question over and over again. Believe me.

Comment: @purplehuman Oh, I know-- in this case, it isn't about preventing repeat questions, it's more for the sake of people who need resolution for review support and suchthelike. The titles of these posts are usually inescapably vague, so I was thinking it might be useful to make room for new threads by renaming old ones. As you and remyabel point out, though (and as I kind of suspect), this kind of effort is not-really-sort-of a piss in the ocean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't.

I've added the [specific-edit](/questions/tagged/specific-edit) tag to ensure that people are able to filter effectively if necessary. This is what tags are for.

Comment: I see, I see. I didn't know about that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `[resolved]` to old question titles is bad for a couple of reasons. It adds clutter to the question title (it's an eye sore), it bumps threads for an inconsequential edit and doesn't improve the question title, and it doesn't indicate *any* useful information to other visitors. All `[resolved]` says is that *one* person was potentially helped. Meta threads tend to be ephemeral. Ideas and opinions are constantly changing and users consistently refer to past contributions by other members because they continue to be useful. Unlike other forums which try to archive discussions as fast as they happen, SO tries to milk as much out of it as possible.

Regardless, it's trying to solve an issue that doesn't exist. Things like `[solved]` are an artifact of abysmal forum software which boast crappy search and crappy user experience. SO is superior in terms of moderation tools, community involvement and collaborative tools.

Answer (score 1):

No you should not. You accepted an answer there, which indicates the issue is resolved (for you as the poster). No further changing is necessary as is indicated in the help-tour to every new user.

And freeing up the title is not necessary. First of all it is not a good title, so why would you make it possible for others to use it and second if you did free it up by adding "[resolved]" and the next user of that title wanted to indicate that it was resolved, how would they free up the title? (Adding `[resolved]` would clash with your changed title).